# "Staple diet" or "Diet staple"

Tags: difference

Are the both phrases correct to use in the sentence below?

It was the **staple diet \ diet staple** of the old stone age people.

Both phrases are common but I am not sure if both are correct.

Comment: I think "staple diet" means foods we eat regularly, and a "diet staple" refers to a specific kind of staple--a staple for diet. We might try diet staples when we're trying to become thinner, usually contains less sugar or fat than its alternatives.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thank you :) I agree. it's possible. But I think it wont be incorrect if I use it in this way too. *"A central problem for both the hunting-magic and food-creation
theories is that the animals that seem to have been diet staples of Old
Stone Age peoples are not those most frequently portrayed. For example,
faunal remains show that the Altamirans ate red deer, not bison."*

Comment: Yes, also this way - https://www.healthtap.com/topics/how-to-eat-rice-as-a-diet-staple

Comment: @GATA, I'm not sure since when *diet* started to hint "weight control". I think it's possible that in that article, it's used in its original sense, "something we eat to sustain our health".

Comment: @GATA this means that each individual animal is a diet staple, and that the animals as a group were part of the staple diet.

Comment: *Staple diet*, I think.

Comment: Thank you all :) Bob, Do you know what makes the "diet staple" suitable for one-kind-of-animal consisted food chain?

Comment: @GATA Answer edited. Kindly note.

Comment: @GATA Here's something: Pasta and olive oil are parts of the Italians' staple diet.  Therefore, pasta is an Italian diet staple and so is olive oil.  Also, the more common term for diet staple is dietary staple.

Comment: @BobRodes I've also found these "food staple" or "staple food" in this article. http://education.nationalgeographic.com/education/encyclopedia/food-staple/?ar_a=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are okay and grammatical. I guess it's similar to how we use 'built-in' or 'in-built'. They may convey the same message and I think it's more about the style than English.

As Damkerng explains (thanks!), *diet staple* refers to a specific kind of staple and Internet results (from authentic sites) return to the phrase used **generally** for dieting, to slim down or lose weight. However, note that *staple* means *main or important* and thus it may not be used with the word *diet.*

See the examples of the definition:

> *figurative violence is the staple diet of the video generation* - [Adjective *staple* meaning: *Main or important, especially in terms of consumption.* #1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/staple) 
>   [staple diet](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/staple-diet) - the main food or foods that a person or animal eats regularly

Comment: Even I felt that way but then if the thing is not so common does not mean incorrect! A little odd but the truth! :)

Comment: Thanks :) It seemed odd to me. The way that Staple(as a noun) has been used in "Diet staple" is not common. I only found this from FreeDictionary "A basic dietary item, such as flour, rice, or corn."

Comment: These are not quite the same.  As Damkerng has said, the staple diet of a group is the food that they eat (all of it), which can be figurative as Maulik's example shows.  A diet staple is one of the foods that the group eats.  Hamburger is a diet staple of Americans, junk food (I'm sorry to say) is our staple diet.

Comment: Staple diet is indeed a much more common expression than diet staple.  Diet staple is a correct expression too.  That does NOT mean that they mean the same thing; they do not.  See [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22diet%20staple%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1992,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) for a number of examples of the correct use of "diet staple".

Comment: @BobRodes What do you think *diet staple* mean then? Kindly explain in the context of OALD example I gave.

Comment: @BobRodes I researched for the phrase and edited the answer.

Comment: @MaulikV Thank you Maulik. Bob's answer seems correct but I don't really understand it. How does "diet staple" imply that?

Comment: Bob's answer is derived from Damkerng's. And Damkerng's concern I mentioned in my edit. That's what it means.

Comment: As for the OALD example you mention, I can see where it is misleading, because if you enter "diet staple" it gives the definition for "staple diet."  This is because search engines, not finding the term "diet staple", reverse the words in an attempt to find a match and show results for "staple diet" instead.  It is not because the two terms have an equivalent meaning.  Again, if you look at several examples of each you will find that the distinction is clear.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, I'd like to point out that "old stone age people" would probably be either redundant or too vague.  From our point of view, everything that occurred in the Stone Age is old.  On the other hand, if you wanted to distinguish between what happened in the Early Stone Age *vs.* the Later Stone Age, then you should use the [appropriate terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Age).  Also note that Stone Age should be capitalized, as it refers to a specific prehistoric period; you aren't using the words "stone" and "age" in their normal sense.

---

Both "staple diet" and "diet staple" are grammatically correct, because both words can be used either as an adjective or as a noun.

However, I would consider "staple diet" to be odd due to possible redundancy.  *Diet*, by definition, encompasses all of the foods that would generally be eaten by a person or a group of people.  Unless there were some weird situation (the Stone Age people had a winter diet that was different from their usual diet), I would just say

> Fish and berries were the diet of the Early Stone Age people.
>
> Fish was the diet staple of the Lower Paleolithic people.  (They got most of their calories from fish, and ate some other foods as well.)